# How add image caption to click-enlarge link in css_styled_content

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Along an upgrade from TYPO3 4.5->6.2, I encountered the following issue:

We have many existing images with text in the "Caption" field, which is in fact named "description". I wanted to rebuild the click-enlarge feature with a given lightbox script and adapt the content rendering by css_styled_content.

Now there is a newer setting in css_styled_content, which enables you to replace the odd/old "click enlarge" behaviour by a regular lightbox (fancybox, colorbox, anybox) style link.

[image]

This comes in very handy. But some lightbox scripts need a title on the link to display that caption when enlarging the image.

How to add that caption to the click-enlarge link?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the field `file:current:description`to the link's `ATagParams`:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap.linkParams.ATagParams.dataWrap =  class="{$styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.lightboxCssClass}" rel="{$styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.lightboxRelAttribute}" title="{file:current:description}"
```